# Using BeautifulSoup to get_text of td tags within a resultset

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am extracting table data using BeautifulSoup from this website:https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2018_gbg.html

There are many tables with a unique table id, that I have been able to extract using the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

stat_dict={'Disposals' : 'sortableTable0',
           'Kicks' : 'sortableTable1',
           'Marks' : 'sortableTable2',
           'Handballs' : 'sortableTable3',
           'Goals' : 'sortableTable4',
           'Behinds' : 'sortableTable5',
           'Hitouts' : 'sortableTable6',
           'Tackles' : 'sortableTable7',
           'Rebounds' : 'sortableTable8',
           'Inside50s' : 'sortableTable9',
           'Clearances': 'sortableTable10',
           'Clangers' : 'sortableTable11',
           'FreesFor' : 'sortableTable12',
           'FreesAgainst' : 'sortableTable13',
           'ContestedPosessions' : 'sortableTable14',
           'UncontestedPosesseions' : 'sortableTable15',
           'ContestedMarks' : 'sortableTable16',
           'MarksInside50' : 'sortableTable17',
           'OnePercenters' : 'sortableTable18',
           'Bounces' : 'sortableTable19',
           'GoalAssists' : 'sortableTable20',
           'Timeplayed' : 'sortableTable21'}

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='...')
url="https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2018_gbg.html"
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

stat_wanted='Disposals'
table = soup.find_all('table', {'id':stat_dict[stat_wanted]})
```

From the table I have extracted, I'd like to do the equivalent of the code below which works if I use soup.find('tbody'). I know that this probably isn't the best or prettiest way of achieve the result, but I'm just playing around with the code to learn how it all works.

```
def get_disposals(team_lower_case, nplayers, nrounds):
    list=[]
    page=requests.get("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/" +str(team_lower_case) +"/2018_gbg.html")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    filter=soup.find('tbody')

    for var in filter.find_all('tr'):
        columns=var.find_all('td')
        for val in columns:
            list.append(val.get_text())
    columns=['PlayerName']

    for n in range(1,nrounds+1):
        columns.append('R'+str(n))

    df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(list).reshape(nplayers,nrounds+1), columns=columns)
    return df

get_disposals("fremantle",30,8)
```

I've tried the code below to get the text from all  tags but the result isn't replicating what I have been able to achieve when extracting the specific table in the first snippet of code.

```
for tr in table:
    zxc=tr.find_all('td')
print(zxc)
for var in zxc:
    list=[]
    list.append(var.get_text())
print(list)
```

But this results in just a list of the  tags and their contents, not the contents you'd expect if get_text was working as I would like it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following approach a bit easier:

```
import pandas as pd    

tables = pd.read_html("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2018_gbg.html")

for df in tables:
    df.drop(df.columns[9:], axis=1, inplace=True)   # remove unwanted columns
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)    # remove extra index level

for table in tables:
    print(table[:3:], '\n')  # show first 3 rows
```

This will give you a list of pandas dataframes. Each one contains all the information for each table. So for example, the first one contains `Disposals`:

```
         Player    R1    R2    R3    R4    R5    R6    R7  Tot
0  Atkins, Rory  14.0  17.0  22.0  28.0  24.0  28.0  16.0  149
1  Betts, Eddie  14.0  20.0  16.0   6.0   NaN   NaN  10.0   66
2   Brown, Luke  15.0  23.0  23.0  16.0  16.0  24.0  11.0  128 

         Player    R1    R2    R3    R4    R5    R6    R7  Tot
0  Atkins, Rory   8.0  13.0  12.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  10.0   94
1  Betts, Eddie   7.0   6.0  10.0   2.0   NaN   NaN   7.0   32
2   Brown, Luke  10.0  17.0  17.0  10.0  11.0  16.0   9.0   90
```

You could then use pandas to work with the data.

Comment: Great - that works a treat.

I've been trying to remove the column headers 'Unnamed: 1_level_0' etc... as well as resetting the index to the 'Disposals' column but can't figure out how to do that?

I've been able to adjust the headings by:
    tables = pd.read_html("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/" +str(team_lower_case)+"/2018_gbg.html",header=1)

Which sets the headers to Player, R1, R2 etc... but not sure about the index?

Comment: You can use `.droplevel(0)` to remove the unwanted index level.