# How do I clean up Beautiful soup's output

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-entities

I am trying to scrape a book from a website and while parsing it with Beautiful Soup I noticed that there were some errors. For example this sentence:

"You have `more&hellip;` direct control over your skaa here. How many woul "Oh, a half dozen or so,"

The `"more&hellip;"` and " woul" are both errors that occurred somewhere in the script.

Is there anyway to automatically clean mistakes like this up?
Example code of what I have is below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://thefreeonlinenovel.com/con/mistborn-the-final-empire_page-1'
res = requests.get(url)
text = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())




trin = soup.tr.get_text()
final = str(trin)
print(final)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using BeautifulSoup to get\_text of td tags within a resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287133/using-beautifulsoup-to-get-text-of-td-tags-within-a-resultset)

Comment: I couldn't find any other way to fix this so I just made another script that uses mostly pandas and it worked fine. Thanks for the info! I am leaving the question up in case someone else can help me to figure out Beautiful Soup some more. As I would love to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the convert the html entities as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string). To apply in your situation however, and retain the text, you can use stripped_strings:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html

url = 'http://thefreeonlinenovel.com/con/mistborn-the-final-empire_page-1'
res = requests.get(url)
text = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

for r in soup.select_one('table tr').stripped_strings:
    s = html.unescape(r)
    print(s)
```